# Java library to find objects in image and create subimages

Tags: java

I have an image with a few items- a car, a person a tree and a mailbox. I want to cut the image around each item and create a sub-image of each. Now I would have one image with a car, one with a person and one with a mailbox. There may be an overlap of other objects, but the predominant feature in each would be the main object.

What library is there that can do this, or at least what technologies that I could merge to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but the question is off-topic because it asks us to recommend a tool or library.

Comment: That's a very easy problem, if you have an exact mathematical definition of "subimage" in terms of RGB pixel values. (Hint: you don't). Did you try searching for "image recognition", "image component analysis", "image component extraction" etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) or [javacv](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/) library for detecting object in the image. It might be possible to process image in real-time or offline

Comment: @waf, the OpenCV library is written in c++, so you could use in iOS easily, http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html